# Simulate Turing machine

Tags: c++, beginner, c++11, state-machine

I have written this code to simulate a Turing machine and wonder what could be improved. In particular, the `--tape.end()` seems a bit dodgy.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>


typedef enum {right, left} Direction;

template<int n>         // n is the number of symbols
struct State {
    std::array<int, n> write;       // Value to write, 0 <= write < n
    std::array<Direction, n> move;  // Direction to move tape
    std::array<State*, n> next;     // Next state, nullptr represents HALT
};

// Some test machines
std::array<State<2>, 5> A = {{
    {{1, 1}, {left, left},   {&A[1],   &A[0]}},
    {{1, 1}, {right, right}, {&A[2],   &A[1]}},
    {{1, 1}, {left, right},  {&A[0],   &A[3]}},
    {{1, 1}, {left, right},  {&A[0],   &A[4]}},
    {{1, 0}, {left, right},  {nullptr, &A[2]}},
}};

std::array<State<2>, 6> B = {{
    {{1, 1}, {left, left},   {&B[1], &B[0]}},
    {{1, 1}, {right, right}, {&B[2], &B[1]}},
    {{0, 1}, {right, right}, {&B[5], &B[3]}},
    {{1, 0}, {left, right},  {&B[0], &B[4]}},
    {{0, 1}, {left, right},  {&B[0], &B[2]}},
    {{1, 1}, {left, left},   {&B[4], nullptr}},
}};

std::array<State<3>, 3> C = {{
    {{1, 1, 2}, {right, left, left},  {&C[1], &C[1], &C[0]}},
    {{1, 1, 2}, {left, right, right}, {&C[0], &C[2], nullptr}},
    {{0, 2, 1}, {left, right, left},  {&C[0], &C[2], &C[2]}},
}};


int main() {
    std::list<int> tape = {0};
    std::list<int>::iterator head = tape.begin();
    State<2>* current_state = &A[0];
    int read;

    unsigned long long int step_count = 0;
    while (true) {
        step_count += 1;
        // Read tape
        read = *head;
        // Write to tape
        *head = current_state->write[read];
        // Move tape head
        if (current_state->move[read] == right) {
            if (head == --tape.end()) {
                tape.push_back(0);
            }
            head++;
        } else if (current_state->move[read] == left) {
            if (head == tape.begin()) {
                tape.push_front(0);
            }
            head--;
        }
        // Change state
        if (current_state->next[read] == nullptr) {
            break;
        } else {
            current_state = current_state->next[read];
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Halted after " << step_count << " steps." << std::endl;
    unsigned int sum = 0;
    for (int it : tape) {
        sum += (it != 0);
    }
    std::cout << "Total non-zeroes: " << sum << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [`std::prev`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev):

```
std::prev(tape.end());
```

The linked page even states the exact comparison of the two:

> Although the expression `--c.end()` often compiles, it is not guaranteed to do so: `c.end()` is an rvalue expression, and there is no iterator requirement that specifies that decrement of an rvalue is guaranteed to work. In particular, when iterators are implemented as pointers, `--c.end()` does not compile, while `std::prev(c.end())` does.

I do have some additional points as well:

1. `typedef` isn't needed for `enum`s in C++.
2. Since `tape` is a storage container of a primitive type (`int`s), the default constructor will zero-initialize it automatically.  As such, you don't need to assign to `{0}`.

   ```
   std::list<int> tape;
   ```

   In case you want to verify it right away, take a look at [this test](http://ideone.com/Kjb1lR).
3. It may be more useful to use [`auto`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) with `head`:

   ```
   auto head = tape.begin();
   ```

   This allows for less typing and for any iterator type (if it ever changes).
4. You could put these "test machines" in a separate file or somewhere separate from the main implementation.  Proper unit testing may be preferred, but I don't have much to say about that.  I'd also rename them as such as it's best not to use single-variable names outside of loop counters.

   Another note: you can omit the `=` for each `std::array` for [C++11 list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization).
5. `main()` seems to be handling too much of the logic.  Have other functions handle it and only have `main()` initialize variables, call these functions, then output the results.
6. `return 0` or similar isn't needed at the very end of `main()`; it'll always do the same return at this point.